# Javascript: Dot notation for dashes?

Tags: javascript

How would I write this in dot notation?

```
req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
```

This does not work

```
req.headers.xForwardedFor
```

Comment: _“How would I write this in dot notation?”_ – you don’t, it’s not possible. (The camelcase notation is only for special objects that explicitly support this, like the `style` object with for example `backgroundColor`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot, since for [dot notation](http://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1) the property name would need to be a [valid identifier name](http://es5.github.io/#x7.6) which must not contain dashes.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't, you can't access an object property with dashes in it using dot notation.